# how to set value of edittext with same id in different inflated linearlayout views?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext

I have one main layout with one LinearLayout. In this LinearLayout I inflates multiple xml layouts that contain a form with multiple text fields(3 EditText) in it.

On first attempt I show only one form. There is button for adding more forms. Suppose If user clicks on **"Add"** button two times then user have three total forms. I successfully get all data of these three forms.

For doing this I am targeting the main layout **"LinearLayout"** and then counting its child. After counting its child I called child views of Main LinearLayout by its position and then get EditText data and save into a list. Then I moved this list to next page. Everything works fine till then. But if user comes back on previous page, all inflated layouts were gone. So, I count the size of list on resume and set the values what users wrote last time.

The problem is when I set the values of EditText according to its view position. Only last object(of list) value is shown in all inflated layouts. Means when for loop ends it sets last object value in all layouts. This is my method for setting  values against a view:

```
private void addFormDataOnResume(LinearLayout viewForm,Traveller otherTraveller)
{
    EditText dateOfBirthEt = (EditText)viewForm.findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);

    dateOfBirthEt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDatePickerDialog(dateOfBirthEt);
        }
    });

    dateOfBirthEt.setText(otherTraveller.getOtherDateOfBirth());

    EditText firstNameET = (EditText)viewForm.findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    firstNameET.setText(otherTraveller.getOtherFirstName());

    EditText lastNameEt = (EditText)viewForm.findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    lastNameEt.setText(otherTraveller.getOtherLastName());
}
```

My loop code:

```
int otherTraSize = otherTravellersData.size();
//adultsForms is the main linear layout in which I am adding views
for(k=0; k < otherTraSize; k++)
{
addFormOnResume();//Function for adding form layout
int viewPos = adultsForms.getChildCount();
if(viewPos>0)
{  
addFormDataOnResume(adultsForms.getChildAt(viewPos-1), otherTravellersData.get(k));
}
}
```

My FUnction for adding forms:

```
private void addFormOnResume()
{
    LinearLayout viewForm = (LinearLayout)layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.other_traveller_form, null );
            adultsForms.addView(viewForm);

}
```

I debug my code, all data of list seems fine. Objects are in proper order with proper values.
Please help me why only last object value is set to all of the inflated forms.

Any help would be really appreciated......Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How you are using the for loop?

Comment: I updated my code for your reference...

Comment: still need `addFormOnResume` are you adding form layouts at position 0 or something instead of adding them at the end..

Comment: Why don't you return the added View from _addFormOnResume()_? You'd pass it to _addFormDataOnResume()_.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare I am adding layout at the end....

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I'll try your suggestion...

Comment: When an Activity is resumed, Android restores its text fields, by ID. Maybe this interferes with what you do. To find out if it is the case, you may log the view instances and the corresponding values (1) right after you add them and [(2) a second later or (2a) when the user presses a button].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your loop code with this:

```
int otherTraSize = otherTravellersData.size();
//adultsForms is the main linear layout in which I am adding views
for(k=0; k < otherTraSize; k++)
{
addFormOnResume();//Function for adding form layout
}

int viewPos = adultsForms.getChildCount();
if(viewPos>0)
{  
   for(int x=0; x<viewPos; x++){
      Log.d("current value",otherTravellersData.get(x).getOtherFirstName());
      addFormDataOnResume(adultsForms.getChildAt(viewPos-1), otherTravellersData.get(x));}
}
```

Comment: Btw I made some edits in my post..Hope you are trying the latest code

Comment: Can you please try updated code and let me know the output of logcat? I want to verify that correct data is being passed or not

Comment: 11-21 16:42:34.374: D/current value(15855): waqas
11-21 16:42:34.394: D/current value(15855): misha
THIS IS THE LOG

Comment: How many times it's getting printed? I mean is it correct for all of your views or same data is being passed?

Comment: Okay do one thing. Try adding different Tags in your child views via setTag in addFormOnResume method and verify in for loop whether correct tag is being sent or not

Comment: All tags are printed correctly....means one tag one time....I think the problem is with Id's of these edittexts.....all layouts have same Id's edittext....loop is setting the last object value to all forms edittexts....you think it can be problem?

Comment: Finally I got the answer of my own question. By default when an activity goes in onPause mode. Android saves the EditText value against an id and when we resume it restore the last saved value of EditText. So, in my case it restoring last form values in all layout forms. The solution of my problem is to set android:saveEnabled="false" on the widget entry on the XML. I added this in all EditText. Android no longer saves my data and onResume I can set value of my form fields whatever I want to, by simply getting childView from specified position even if they have same Id. :)

Comment: My Pleasure to help  :)

Answer (score 4):

Finally I got the answer of my own question. By default when an activity goes in onPause mode. Android saves the EditText value against an id and when we resume it restore the last saved value of EditText. So, in my case it restoring last form values in all layout forms. The solution of my problem is to set **android:saveEnabled="false"** on the widget entry on the XML. I added this in all EditText. Android no longer saves my data and onResume I can set value of my form fields whatever I want to, by simply getting childView from specified position even if they have same Id.

Answer (score -1):

Its my working code

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnAdd:
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_materials, null);
            parentLinearLayout.addView(view);
            arrayList.add(view);

            edtMaterialName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtinput_material1);
            editTextCoast = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextCoast1);

            edtMaterialName.addTextChangedListener(getMyTextWatcher(edtMaterialName,arrayListMaterials.size()-1 ,"name"));
            editTextCoast.addTextChangedListener(getMyTextWatcher(editTextCoast, arrayListMaterials.size()-1,  "cost"));

            break;




TextWatcher getMyTextWatcher(final EditText edtText, final int listPosition, String nameOrcost){
            return new MyTextWatcher(edtText, listPosition, nameOrcost);
        }




class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher{
    int position;
    EditText edtText;
    String nameOrcost;
    MaterialData data;
    boolean flag;
    int count;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText edtText1, int listPosition, String nameOrcost){
        this.position = listPosition;
        this.edtText=edtText1;
        this.nameOrcost = nameOrcost;
        data = arrayListMaterials.get(position);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable sEditable) {
        try{
        if(this.nameOrcost.equals("name") && edtText.getEditableText().toString().length()>0){
            data.setMaterialName(edtText.getEditableText().toString());
        }
        if(this.nameOrcost.equals("cost") && edtText.getEditableText().toString().trim().length()>0){
            String tempCost = edtText.getEditableText().toString().trim();
            NumberFormat myFormatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            Number number = myFormatter.parse(tempCost);

            data.setMaterialprice(new BigDecimal(number.toString()).toString());
        }
        arrayListMaterials.set(position, data);
        setTotalPrice(arrayListMaterials);
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(this.nameOrcost.equals("cost") && edtText.getEditableText().toString().trim().length()>0){
            Utilty.insertCommaIntoNumber(edtText, sEditable.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        try{    
            if(this.nameOrcost.equals("cost"))
            data.setMaterialprice("0");

            if(this.nameOrcost.equals("name"))
            data.setMaterialName("");

            arrayListMaterials.set(position, data);

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }


}
```